# Literals filtering without language tag

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena

I'm trying to filter some Strings by a specific language but they are literals without language tags, so I can't filter them with "lang" or "langMatches". It is like all the results respond to all the languages, how can I filter it?

I'm using the Java Jena libraries and I have already tried to use the "regex" functionality but it gives me all the results as they respond to all languages.

Here is the query to show all the results and the languages

```
String TitleQuery =
      "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>"+
      "SELECT ?title ?language "+
      "WHERE { ?s dc:title ?title ."+
      "?s dc:language ?language ."+
      "}";
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| title                                 | language     |
========================================================
| "Espainiako Erkidego Autonomoak"      | "Euskera"    |
| "Espainiako Erkidego Autonomoak"      | "Portuguese" |
| "Espainiako Erkidego Autonomoak"      | "English"    |
| "Espainiako Erkidego Autonomoak"      | "Català"     |
| "Espainiako Erkidego Autonomoak"      | "Italiano"   |
| "Espainiako Erkidego Autonomoak"      | "Français"   |
| "Espainiako Erkidego Autonomoak"      | "Deutsch"    |
| "Espainiako Erkidego Autonomoak"      | "Galego"     |
| "Espainiako Erkidego Autonomoak"      | "Español"    |
| "Comunità autonome della Spagna"      | "Euskera"    |
| "Comunità autonome della Spagna"      | "Portuguese" |
| "Comunità autonome della Spagna"      | "English"    |
| "Comunità autonome della Spagna"      | "Català"     |
| "Comunità autonome della Spagna"      | "Italiano"   |
| "Comunità autonome della Spagna"      | "Français"   |
| "Comunità autonome della Spagna"      | "Deutsch"    |
| "Comunità autonome della Spagna"      | "Galego"     |
| "Comunità autonome della Spagna"      | "Español"    |
| "Comunitats Autònomes d'Espanya"      | "Euskera"    |
[...]
```

This is the regex filter that I've tried: `FILTER regex(str(?language),\"Español\")`

And these are the results, every result matches with every language:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| title                                 | language  |
=====================================================
| "Espainiako Erkidego Autonomoak"      | "Español" |
| "Comunità autonome della Spagna"      | "Español" |
| "Comunitats Autònomes d'Espanya"      | "Español" |
| "Comunidades autónomas de España"     | "Español" |
| "Comunidades Autónomas da Espanha"    | "Español" |
| "Communautés Autonomes d'Espagne"     | "Español" |
| "Autonome Gemeinschaften von Spanien" | "Español" |
| "Autonomous Communities of Spain"     | "Español" |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That's the most basic part of SPARQL isn't it? Just write the URI or Literal instead of the variable: `?s dc:language "English" .` or use a `FILTER(?language = "English")` or use `VALUES ?language {"English" "Deutsch"}`

Comment: And please show the REGEX you tried. I can't believe that it returns all results.

Comment: Yes, it should be so simple, and I'm sorry if I'm asking basic questions but I'm new with this and I've been trying to do it for so long. I've edited the post with the regex filter and the results, that are the same that with your options. Thank you for your help! @AKSW

Comment: Well, now I see the problem. You query can't work. Both title and language are just defined for the resources. So a single resource lets say `:r1` has some titles `t1, t2, ..., tn` and some languages `l1, l2, ..., ln` . But you need some relation between title and language which you don't have.  Who created the dataset, it doesn't make sense in its current form. Either a blank node is need for each pair (title, language) like `r1 :hasTitle [:value :t1; :language :l1]` or the titles must use language tags. Otherwise your lost. The problem is not your query but the dataset

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both title and language are just defined for the resources. So a single resource, lets say `:r1`, has some titles `t1, t2, ..., tn` and some languages `l1, l2, ..., ln`. But you need some relation between title and language which you don't have.

The dataset doesn't make sense in its current form. Either a blank node is need for each pair (title, language) like `r1 :hasTitle [:value :t1; :language :l1]` or the titles must use language tags. Otherwise you're lost. The problem is not your query but the dataset.